# Enabling cache in sending http requests(Android, JAVA)

Tags: android, caching, http-get

Just like a normal web browser, e.g, chrome,firefox, where cache is enabled, I want to send a http get request from my android activity using HTTPGET which will handle caching. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use [Volley](https://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/training/volley/index.html) Library for all Networking Calls to make it more easier, efficient and fast.

Use it for caching the Requests and Memory Management.

**Loading request from cache**
Like below you can check for a cached response of an URL before making a network call.

```
Cache cache = AppController.getInstance().getRequestQueue().getCache();
Entry entry = cache.get(url);
if(entry != null){
 try {
    String data = new String(entry.data, "UTF-8");
    // handle data, like converting it to xml, json, bitmap etc..
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
else{
// Cached response doesn't exists. Make network call here
}
```

Hope this helps !!

Comment: returning error "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'AppController.getRequestQueue()' on a null object reference